# xcode 6 installing -> image not recognized

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to install xcode 6 but when I double tap dmg icon, the popup appears and it tells me "The following disk image couln't be opened. Image not recognized."

Please, can you help me? Where is the problem?

Comment: Is your registration as an Apple developer up-to-date? If so, I'd say try the Xcode 6 download again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the beta version once again as downloading was stopped in between due to some issue and you might have started it again. i also faced the same issue. re downloading helped.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when trying to install Xcode 6 Mac told me that the image was not recognized. After downloading it again everything went fine.